# Cannot convert Keras model with custom metric to tflite

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

Here is my model:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()
# layer 1
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(8, 5, padding='same', input_shape=(112,112,3)))
model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(keras.layers.Activation(activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(strides=2, padding='same'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
# layer 2
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 5, padding='same'))
model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(keras.layers.Activation(activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(strides=2, padding='same'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
# layer 3
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(24, 5, padding='same'))
model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(keras.layers.Activation(activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(strides=2, padding='same'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
# layer 4
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 5, padding='same'))
model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(keras.layers.Activation(activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(strides=2, padding='same'))
# Global avg pooling before fully connected. Can use Flatten instead to experiment
model.add(keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D())
# Fully Connected
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(7, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=[categorical_accuracy, top_3_accuracy, top_2_accuracy])
print(model.summary())
```

After training and saving the model, I can load it from  the file and use it.
To load and use it, I use the following code:

```
def top_3_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return top_k_categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred, k=3)


def top_2_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return top_k_categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred, k=2)


keras.metrics.top_3_accuracy = top_3_accuracy
keras.metrics.top_2_accuracy = top_2_accuracy

model = load_model(model_path + 'mymodel.hdf5')
print(model.summary())
```

I followed the method as mentioned in [tensorflow lite docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/python_api). However, when I try to convert it to tflite I get an error.
converting to tflite:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras.engine.saving import load_model
from keras.metrics import top_k_categorical_accuracy
from config import model_path


def top_3_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return top_k_categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred, k=3)


def top_2_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return top_k_categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred, k=2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # to convert using custom metric
    keras.metrics.top_3_accuracy = top_3_accuracy
    keras.metrics.top_2_accuracy = top_2_accuracy
    model_name = 'mymodel'
    model_file = model_path + model_name + '.hdf5'  
    # model = load_model(model_file) ## this line works

    converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file(model_file) # throws error
    tflite_model = converter.convert()
    open(model_path+model_name+'_lite.tflite', 'wb').write(tflite_model)
```

I get the following error:
     `ValueError: Unknown metric function:top_3_accuracy`

I'm using tensorflow 1.13 and keras 2.2.4

Comment: TensorFlow Lite has support for limited operations currently. See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_compatibility). The procedure for custom ops is [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_custom)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me and I it will work you too:

```
import tensorflow as tf
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file('model.h5',custom_objects= 
{'top_2_accuracy':top_2_accuracy,'top_3_accuracy':top_3_accuracy}) 
tfmodel = converter.convert() 
open ("model.tflite" , "wb") .write(tfmodel)
```